# How to join, and intersect objects?

Tags: vertices, edges, vertex-groups, groups

[image]

How do I join this two arcs in a way to connect the vertices (a vertice that connect and join these two objects). (on top and bottom).

[image]

(zoom of the picture on the top pf the object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the two edges intersect:

[image]

1. Select edge1 and create a new [Transform Orientation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/transform/control/orientations.html#custom-orientations) from the edge's normal orientation.
2. Select edge2 and snap the cursor to it. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > Cursor to Selected
3. [Subdivide](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/surfaces/editing.html#subdivision) edge1 and select the created vertice. <kbd>W</kbd> > <kbd>S</kbd>
4. Set the *[Pivot center for rotation/scaling](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html#pivot-point)* to *[3D Cursor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/transform/control/pivot_point/3d_cursor.html#d-cursor)* with <kbd>.</kbd>.
5. Scale the vertice to 0 along its local Y axis. <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

[image]

6. Delete edge2 [(<kbd>X</kbd>)](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/deleting.html?highlight=only) and connect the vertices (<kbd>F</kbd>).

[image]

Comment: But it is faster to use the TinyCAD-Addons dedicated operator.